# Bootstrap mobile menu a bullet point list?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, menu

I have a template that uses bootstrap. I am a complete beginner with such things. The menu looks all wrong when using mobile screen size (android, moto G7 size). It is basically a full screen grey box with bullet points to select next to it.

You can see it if you like here: stuttgart-hypnobirthing.de

Any idea what is wrong and how I can fix it? Thank you!

PS: if I know what code the problem is, I will post it. For now I have no idea that is why I posted the link.

EDIT after @tao comment on 11.12.19

```css
#mainav form{display:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
#mainav form select, #mainav form select option{display:block; cursor:pointer; outline:none;}
#mainav form select{width:100%; padding:5px; border:1px solid;}
#mainav form select option{margin:5px; padding:0; border:none;}

body, input, textarea, select{font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;}
```

Comment: You have a lot more chances of getting help on [so] if your question is useful for future readers. Currently, if you get a useful answer the code on your website will change and the question will no longer be relevant, therefore useful. Ideally, you should add a [mcve] in the question itself. And please read [ask].

Comment: The reason why your dropdown menu looks like it does has little to nothing to do with `twitter-bootstrap`. Your menu is a `<select>` tag with `<font>`s inside its `<option>`s. It's an unfortunate choice of elements: `<font>` has been deprecated since HTML 4 and has been removed in HTML 5 (which means browsers are free to drop support for it completely). As for `<select>`, it's unstyle-able cross-browser. Bootstrap uses either `<div>`s or `<ul>`s for its [dropdown menus](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/).

Comment: @tao - thank you very much for your answer. I looked in my index.html file and did not find the tags you refer to anywhere. I assume you mean what is in my layout.css file?

`#mainav form{display:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
#mainav form select, #mainav form select option{display:block; cursor:pointer; outline:none;}
#mainav form select{width:100%; padding:5px; border:1px solid;}
#mainav form select option{margin:5px; padding:0; border:none;}`

So what is my best bet? I googled and found this: 
[link]https://github.com/thdoan/pretty-dropdowns[] - should I install this plugin?